# How to calculate and add custom properties to results retrieved from OData API?

Tags: c#, odata

I am retrieving data from OData (v.3) API, and displaying it in a table, in console:

```
Item Name  Price Difference
aaa        10    0
bbb        2     8
ccc        5     -3
```

`Item Name` and `Price` are properties retrieved from the API. `Difference` is the difference I am calculating between the price of one item retrieved and the price of the next item retrieved. I do not need to modify the data in the API, only export the data in table in JSON format, with each item having `Difference` as a property.

How is it possible to add the `Difference` property to the entity? I've googled a lot, and most questions deal with modifying data in the API and similar.

Comment: Do you need to have `Difference` only for this console app or you want to provide this service wide, so every call to return a result with `Difference` field ? If it is the first case - all you have to do is to project returned results to a new form (a new type with difference property), if it is the later - you most likely will need to change the service.

Comment: Is it possible for you to extend entity to have `Item Name, Price, Difference` and map the data to from API to Item Name, Price, and calculate the difference. and render the entity to JSON.

If not possible to update entity, can you create a separate class with `Item Name, Price & Difference`, and map the data from API entity to newly created entity and render to JSON.

Comment: @Dimitar I only need it for this console app.

Comment: Then you just need a new type with the additional property and projection. If you provide a concrete type returned from the service, I can be more specific about  approach.

Comment: @Dimitar thanks, I did that and it works! Thanks Sibgath too